# Comet Implementation for GWT

Tags: gwt, comet, server-push

Does anyone know another comet implementation for GWT, i'm using this one http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/ but getting error with firefox and gwt. I've listes the error at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693964/gwt-comet-error

Comment: If you've already asked the question, why are you asking again?

Comment: I'm trying to know if there is another implementation of comet for GWT!!

Comment: Another Comet implementation is available from the Rocket GWT project: http://code.google.com/p/rocket-gwt/wiki/Comet

Answer (score 1):

You can use Atmosphere Framework:
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere

They support GWT